# Display array using method and case

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, case

Hi I wrote a case where it should display the array from my method, but the method I wrote wont return the value back up to my case instead it gives me a blue error code. I want to be able to select my case and let it display my array. If you could help me I be very thank full.

These are all the code belonging to this case I believe. thanks again.

```
            int selection;
            do
            {
            int[] A = { -2, 5, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 };

            DisplayMenu();

            Console.Write("Enter your selection");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out selection);

            switch(selection)
            {
            case 6:
                    ShowArray(A); //<<<<<display array here
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();



            static void DisplayMenu()
            {
            Console.WriteLine("t6");
            }



             static int ShowArray(int[] array)//<<<<here return value top
            {
            Console.WriteLine("\n=============\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
            Console.Write("{0}", array[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n=============\n");
            }
```

Comment: what does static mean static int ShowArray(int[] array) here?
and you are not returning anu "Int" from this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to display your array to the console, and not actually return a value from that method, change the signature from this:

```
static int ShowArray(int[] array)
```

To this:

```
static void ShowArray(int[] array)
```

- A return type of `int` means you'll return an integer before the method exits.
- A return type of `void` means you won't be returning anything, which seems to be what you want.